# Ping transmit general failure on Windows

Tags: windows-7, dns, firewall, ethernet, wired-networking

We have a windows 7 system with static IP and DNS in our network. From last couple of days, the network icon on taskbar is displaying red cross. I can't ping PC's static IP, gateway, DNS even loopback address (127.0.0.1). After performing ping command, I get `Ping transmit general failure error. 100% packet loss.`

Tried checking I/O ports, DNS flushing, reinstalling ethernet drivers. Nothing resolves the issue. RJ45 adapter orange and yellow lights are also blinking. I was thinking of performing a system restore, but sadly no restore point has been created in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Control Panel, Device Manager and expand to see the Network Card. Is there a Red or Yellow error Icon there?  If so, the card may be bad as per above (run Vendor Hardware tests to see). You can try updating the driver from there, but be sure to run the hardware tests.

Comment: I'm getting Red cross. I'll just try installing an external ethernet jack. And check if it works.

Comment: Just an update, I tried installing external USB ethernet. Didn't work. So I just reinstalled Windows and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to ping an IPv6 address but IPv6 wasn't enabled on my router (Google Home). I had to:

1. Open Google Home App
2. Find my WiFi router
3. Go to Settings > Network Settings > Advanced Networking
4. Toggle on IPv6.

Note the first time I did this it said something about error. I went back in and retried and it worked. Now my IPv6 ping is working.